# Is there any way to cancel removal order using amazon MWS API?

Tags: amazon-mws, cancellation

I want to cancel the removal order through MWS API. But I didn't found any information to cancel removal order using MWS api. Then i found removal orders are setup the same as customer orders.

So,I just tried FeedType(but getting error in Get Feed Submission Result as shown in screenshot):

- `_POST_FULFILLMENT_ORDER_CANCELLATION_REQUEST_DATA_`

  - https://prnt.sc/132vcpm
- `_POST_FLAT_FILE_FULFILLMENT_ORDER_CANCELLATION_REQUEST_DATA_`

  - https://nimb.ws/YhcTpb

Can anyone suggest me the MWS API So I can cancel removal order using my code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `_POST_PAYMENT_ADJUSTMENT_DATA_`

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/OrderAdjustment.xsd